# Should ValueObject be merged by static method inside class or by a util class? Using C# and DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Recently I saw code like the following to Merge two ValueObjects to a new ValueObject:

```
public class SomeValueObject
{
    public readonly string A;
    public readonly string B;

    public SomeValueObject(string a, string b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public static SomeValueObject Merge(SomeValueObject preferred, SomeValueObject fallback)
    {
        return new SomeValueObject(
            preferred.A ?? fallback.A,
            preferred.B ?? fallback.B);
    }
}
```

The code was called then inside the Application Layer.

My questions:

1. Is this good practice to do the merge of ValueObjects like in the example or should therefore a Util class be used?
2. When I think, that then there could be also other static methods, e.g. to create some ValueObject from properties of two or more other ValueObject, I would prefer to create a Util class for this functionality. Or is it a good practice to do that in a static method of the returned ValueObject?

   ```
   public class SomeValueObject
   {
       public readonly string A;
       public readonly string B;

       public SomeValueObject(string a, string b)
       {
           A = a;
           B = b;
       }

       public static SomeValueObject Merge(SomeValueObject preferred, SomeValueObject fallback)
       {
           return new SomeValueObject(
               preferred.A ?? fallback.A,
               preferred.B ?? fallback.B);
       }

       public static SomeValueObject FromOtherObjects(SomeOtherValueObject  someOtherValueObject, SomeSecondOtherValueObject someSecondOtherValueObject)
       {
           return new SomeValueObject(someOtherValueObject.Foo, someSecondOtherValueObject.bar);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Corresponding to question 2, I would have dependency to the other classes inside my class, but they are not really part of my class (properties). When one of the other classes also would have a method with SomeValueObject then I would have classes that are cross dependent on each other.

Personally I would prefer the Util class but I don't know if this is a overhead...

Comment: I don't see how DDD is relevent in your questions...

Comment: I would leave them as in the code that you *found*, with static method inside the ValueObject class. The reason is encapsulation of data and behavior and high cohesion.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this good practice to do the merge of ValueObjects like in the example or should therefore a Util class be used?

The common case is that the functions for manipulating values are part of the definition of the value, and so packaged with it, rather than in some separate utility class.

ValueObjects are expected to be objects after all -- functions and data both together.

> I would have dependency to the other classes inside my class, but they are not really part of my class (properties). When one of the other classes also would have a method with SomeValueObject then I would have classes that are cross dependent on each other.

Circular dependencies are (a) often an indication that there are improvements to be made in your model and (b) not necessarily a critical problem if the two values are closely related anyway.